# Ubuntu 16.04 - Couldn't find any package by glob and regex [VPS]

Tags: command-line, vpn, vps

I keep getting this error:

[image: Error]

I only started using Ubuntu 2 days ago and I am not exactly sure what it means. Can someone please help me?

I am trying to turn it into a VPN.

Comment: You are using `apt-get` instead of `dpkg`. BTW you should not need to install `openvpn` by manually downloading a DEB file, it's in the repositories.

Comment: By in the repositories does that mean I can just install it straight off the bat? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: dpkg -i openvpn-as-2.1.4b-Ubuntu16.amd_64.deb worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it working with the following command:

```
dpkg -i openvpn-as-2.1.4b-Ubuntu16.amd_64.deb
```